# How to link to a folder in a different location?

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj, projects-and-solutions

In C# Project files as written by Visual Studio or SharpDevelop, files that are not located in the folder hierarchy of a project can be included with a `<Link>` element.<sup>1</sup>

My directory structure looks like this:

```
[SolutionDirectory]
 |- [MyProject]
 |   |- TestProj.csproj
 |- [File]
 |   |- somefile.txt
 |- TestProj.sln
```

Hence, in *TestProj.csproj*, I can add the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\File\somefile.txt">
        <LogicalName>MyResource</LogicalName>
        <Link>somefile.txt</Link>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works flawlessly, and *somefile.txt* is embedded as a resource. The project tree is shown as follows by SharpDevelop 4.4:

[image: project with linked file]

However, to make things tidier, I would like to organize files like *somefile.txt* in a folder hierarchy within *TestProj.csproj*. I have tried the following:

**Just adapting the `<Link>`:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\File\somefile.txt">
        <LogicalName>MyResource</LogicalName>
        <Link>File\somefile.txt</Link>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Declaring a folder of the desired name:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\File\somefile.txt">
        <LogicalName>MyResource</LogicalName>
        <Link>File\somefile.txt</Link>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Folder Include="File" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Declaring the actual folder as a link:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\File\somefile.txt">
        <LogicalName>MyResource</LogicalName>
        <Link>File\somefile.txt</Link>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Folder Include="..\File">
        <Link>File</Link>
    </Folder>
</ItemGroup>
```

All of these yield the same result: The folder structure in the project is shown as desired, however, the *File* folder is marked with a yellow exclamation mark warning sign, implying that something is not quite all right:

[image: project with linked file in a folder; the folder shows a warning symbol]

The only way I have found to make this warning symbol go away is to actually create an additional *File* folder in the project directory:

```
[SolutionDirectory]
 |- [MyProject]
 |   |- [File]
 |   |- TestProj.csproj
 |- [File]
 |   |- somefile.txt
 |- TestProj.sln
```

As gets visible here, this additional *File* folder would remain empty, and [empty directories is only possible with workarounds for version control systems such as Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository). (Possibly, the same restriction applies to some archive formats.)

Therefore, I am still trying to find a better solution: **How can I link to files outside of the folder structure of my project and sort them into an otherwise empty folder hierarchy within my project?**

Unfortunately, the [MSBuild Schema Reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) does not even mention the `<Folder>` element, so I failed to find out anything about the issue via the docs.

<sup>1</sup>: In general, this serves for including files in several projects. In my particular case, I am working on a project that needs to reference a class library in the same solution, but it also needs to include the entire source code (including the project file etc.) of that class library as an embedded resource.

Comment: Do you need all the source code files as individual embedded resources, or will 1 zip suffice?

Comment: @Balah: I have considered embedding the zipped sources as a single resource, but I'm not sure whether it's possible to configure the project files to embed a zip file as a resource that is zipped on the fly. I might have to work with pre-build events and call an external zip application, although that would introduce a dependency to have such a zip application on the path again ... possible, although not optimal.

Comment: Ah I think you're going to have to have pre-build events and they can zip on the fly... although... you don't necessarily have to use an external zip application - iff you're using .NET 4.5 and above (using the ZipFile class). I had a similar problem that I solved some time back using MsBuild inline tasks and tweaking the build order. I'll post an answer once I find the code somewhere

Comment: @Balah: I'm considering whether to create a separate question for that, so you can add your answer there. Your solution could help me in my current situation, but it is considerably different to what I am asking here (and it's not nice for future visitors to find a question that asks exactly what they want - linking to folders in other locations - and find that the OP accepted an answer that solved their underlying problem, but not the problem explicitly asked about).

Comment: I share your sentiment. Have you tried using [Shared Projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-vs#VSIDE). I'm yet to try it myself but apparently "...the code and assets in the shared project are treated as if they were files linked into the main project..."